# How to debug a windows executable which is crashing

Tags: windows, executable

How Can I debug a windows executable which is crashing ? I have project.pdb and vc90.pdb file along with the executable.

How can I use visual studio to load the executable and pdb files to debug the crashing issue ?

Thanks

Deepak

Comment: If you do not have the code then the only thing you can see is the exception it is throwing. You cannot change the code

Comment: Use windbg. http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html

Answer (score 0):

From "Developer Command line", run:

```
%DevEnvDir%\devenv.exe /debugexe c:\my.exe <params to my.exe>
```

It will probably stop at the crashing exception location, and you should be able to examine the stack trace and hopefully learn something about its cause.